# How to Login with Random users everytime with gatling?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

my scenario is like, I have to create a script for **which randomly takes 10 users for login and logout**. **The code I have written logins same user 10 times it does not take random number.** How to do this?

Below is my code outputs same user login 10 times instead of taking different users.

```
// Login and Logout random users
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class random extends Simulation {

 val testServerUrl = System.getProperty("Url", "https://url")
 val username = System.getProperty("username", "TestUser")
 val password = System.getProperty("password", "password")
 val userCount = Integer.getInteger("userCount", 10).toInt
 val startNum = Integer.getInteger("EndNumber", 1).toInt
 val endNum = Integer.getInteger("EndNumber", 100).toInt

 val httpProtocol = http
 .baseURL(testServerUrl)

 val scn = scenario("random")
 .exec(http("Login")
 .post("/security_check")
 .headers(headers_9)
 .formParam("j_username", username + ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt(startNum, endNum))
 .formParam("j_password", password)
 .resources(
 http("Fetch_IDs")
 .get("/desktop/s_nav.jsp")
 .check(regex("""current_account_id=(\d+)""").saveAs("accountID"))
 .check(regex("""current_workspace_id=(\d+)""").saveAs("workspaceID"))
 .headers(headers_5)
 ))

 .exec(http("Logout")
 .post("/logoutcontroller")
 .headers(headers_9)
 .formParam("action", "logout")
 .formParam("undefined", "")
 .formParam("current_account_id", "${accountID}")
 .formParam("current_workspace_id", "${workspaceID}"))

 setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(userCount))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.formParam("j_username", session => username +  ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt(endNum))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your random generator inside the scenario val is only called once when the scenario is generated.

What you want to do is use a feeder, that injects random values in each execution of your scenario.

Gatling has a very nice documentation with examples for feeder which you can find here:
http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/session/feeder.html

and here (step 03):
http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/advanced_tutorial.html